# Chain PowerShell Class Functions

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to chain class functions in PowerShell like this?

```
$vm = [VirtualMachine]::new().Create().Start()
```

I am getting an error:

> It is not possible to call a method for an expression that has the
> NULL

So probably not?

Comment: If you have access to the source code, then ```Create()``` and ```Start()``` can be modified to return the object instance ```$this```  - then you would be able to chain calls (a.k.a a “fluent interface” - see the “Implementation” section of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), but there’s nothing you can really do on the caller side to retro-fit it onto objects at runtime…

Comment: Ok thx a lot, that already help :) Is this something you can do or rather a no-go?

Comment: There’s no features in Powershell to change the return type unless you modify the source code. If you *really* need a fluent interface you could wrap the ```VirtualMachine``` class in your own Powershell class that *does* return the instance from its wrapper methods for ```Create``` and ```Start``` but that’s a lot of extra work just to save a couple of lines at the call site…